# Easiest method to save external rss feeds

Tags: php, cakephp, rss, external

I have big problem, I want to read rss feeds from mydealz.de and save their titles, contents and dates to my db. I'm using cakephp, is there any easy way to do it? I'm simply out of ideas

I was trying to do that from this tutorial : http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://blog.loadsys.com/2009/06/19/cakephp-rss-feed-datasource/&usg=AFQjCNFhFxVyjqEFoPFfZgt-X2NYpmv0OQ but in model I delclared that I'm not using database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
App::import('Core', 'HttpSocket');
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$input = $HttpSocket->get('http://www.example.com/something.xml');

App::import('Xml'); 
$xml = new Xml($input);
$xmlAsArray = $xml->toArray();

foreach($xmlAsArray as $item) {
    $this->Article->create();
    $data['Article'] = array(
        'title' => $item['title'],
        'contents' => $item['contents'],
        'date' => $item['date']
    );
    $this->Article->save($data);
}
```